# Customize visual studio code landing page

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I open a project in visual studio code I get this screen:

[image]

I want to customize that screen on a per-project basis, so that I can do things like provide links to relevant documentation, describe the project architecture and otherwise communicate to anyone who is collaborating on the project - similar to a MOTD. I'm imagining a .md or .html file in the root directory of my project that is read by VSC as that would also allow my team to provide different landing screens per branch. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using the Settings >> Workbench >> Startup Editor field and setting it to "readme". maintaining a README.md file in any project is a big advantage because most Source Control management sites such as github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc. present this same README on the project overview page.